# derivate conserves the sign in a neighborhood?

Tags: calculus

If the derivate of a function is positive in a point, is there a neighborhood of the point in which the derivate is also positive? (because the derivate function has properties similar to a continuous functions...)

Comment: From your assumptions the derivative may not even exist in another point.

Comment: > (because the derivate function has properties similar to a continuous functions...) All derivatives are not continuous. The property you stated, will hold only for continuous derivatives (and thus surely for derivatives of doubly differentiable functions which are a subset).

Comment: ?????The answer is affirmative when the limit of the derivate exists since the discontinuities of the derivate can be only of second kind

Comment: @Michael Hoppe OK, I am asking in the case the derivate exists in a neighborhood of the point.

Comment: *"all derivatives are not continuous"* I guess a quantifier wasn't properly negated here, since there are clearly derivatives which are continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Take 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x/2 + x^2 \sin(1/x) & \text{for $x\neq 0$}\\
0 & \text{for $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
You have 
$$
f'(x) = \frac 1 2 + 2x \sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x)
$$
for $x\neq 0$ and $f'(0) = 1/2$ by direct computation.

Notice that $f'(1/(2\pi k)) = - \frac 1 2$ hence $f'(0)>0$ but in every neighbourhood of $0$ there are points where $f'<0$.

Of course when $f'$ is continuous, the property is satisfied, hence the example must exhibit a function which is differentiable but with a derivative which is not continuous at a point. Moreover Darboux property implies that the limit of the derivative does not exists in the point.

Comment: Yes I also found sequences in which the sign of the derivate is different. Thanks.

Comment: The answer is affirmative when the limit of the derivate exists since the discontinuities of the derivate can be only of second kind

Comment: Thank you,
The answer is affirmative when the limit of the derivate exists since the discontinuities of the derivate can be only of second kind.

Comment: Sure. If the limit of the derivative exists, then the derivative is continuous in the point, so if it is positive in the point it is positive in a neighbourhood of the point.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: Your example serves to illustrate another point. When $f'(a) > 0$ it means that there will be a neighborhood $I$ of $a$ such that $f(x) < f(a)$ for $x < a, x \in I$ and $f(x) > f(a)$ for $x > a, x \in I$. And then we call that $f$ is "strictly increasing at $x = a$". The above example clearly demonstrates that if $f$ is strictly increasing at $a$ it does not necessarily mean that there is a neighborhood of $a$ in which $f$ is strictly increasing because in this example any neighborhood of $x = 0$ contains points where derivative is negative.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini: I am sorry if this comment offended you. I just added a statement related to your example. My comment was meant to add something to what you have written and not replace it. probably I should have worded like "illustrating one more point" rather than "another point".